# Can't delete multiple files at once in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

This is weird, but I can't delete multiple files at once in Windows 8. Files are on my desktop, I'm selecting them with Ctrl+left click. After that delete option is disappearing from the right click menu, delete button on the keyboard also doesn't work.

Is that a bug? Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: You may be selecting a shortcut like Computer, Recycling Bin, IE that cannot be removed along with user files.

Comment: @kobaltz oh, you're right, thanks! :) ... please post an answer, so I can accept it. :)

Comment: What files are you selecting, can you delete each one indivualy, my guess you will find one you can't.  Nothing change with Windows 8 with regards to deleting files.

Comment: I was accidentally chosen the `Recycle Bin` icon also, it solved now. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete everything *except* for the recycle bin, and if you select it along with other files, the deletion will fail without any error.

Lack of error is not very user friendly maybe, but you can just avoid the recycle bin and it will work.

**EDIT**

Icons placed on the desktop by an administrator are also impossible to delete as a regular user, however in that case you should see a dialog asking you to login as an administrator.

Answer (score 1):

You may be selecting a shortcut like Computer, Recycling Bin, IE that cannot be removed along with user files.

Comment: I believe it is *only* the Recycle Bin - the others are not even there by default.

Comment: It depends on how your Computer icon was placed on the desktop. If you just created a shortcut then yes, it can be deleted like normal. However, if you create it using the Personalization, then you may have an issue. The same goes for Network Neighborhood, My Documents, Internet Explorer, etc.

Comment: I just tried: `Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Personalization` -> Change desktop icons -> Tick all - deleting them is still possible. However, I would expect that if it is an administrator doing this operation, they would indeed be undeletable